# Why cant i use the field user in SQL Server 8?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, syntax

Maybe not literally but the query below gets an error near user. If i change it to userZ it works. WHY can i not use that name? Is there a way to specific its a field instead of a keyword? (or whatever it is)

```
create table Post2 (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
title nvarchar(max)
 NOT NULL,
body nvarchar(max)
 NOT NULL,
user integer REFERENCES Post1(id));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reserved words, like `user` should be enclosed in brackets.
Take a look at [Using Identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa223962%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx) for a more in depth explanation.

```
CREATE TABLE Post2 (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
  , title NVARCHAR(MAX)NOT NULL
  , body NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
  , [User] INTEGER REFERENCES Post1(id)
);
```

Comment: However, it should be pointed out that using reserved words is a poor practice to be avoided not just gotten around.

Answer (score 2):

USER is a reserved word.

Try delimiting it with "" (e.g. "user" or [user])

[Read more on using delimited identifiers here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224033%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx)